# Leave one out cross validation for rare events logistic regression in SPSS

Tags: logistic, spss, cross-validation, rare-events

I am writing thesis about predicting which corporate takeover targets attract a competing bidder. I first estimated a model using a logistic regression. The sample consists of 1350 single-bidder targets and 51 multiple-bidder targets.

I want to test the predictive ability with a holdout sample and use this prediction to construct a portfolio that generates more returns than the market (CAR); however this holdout sample has 250 single-bidder targets and only 13 multiple-bidder targets.

1. Does it matter for the holdout sample that the number of multiple-bidder target is so small?
2. Would a "leave-one-out-cross-validation" (LOOCV) be superior to the holdout sample to test the predictive ability? i.e. not model accuracy
3. How I can do a "leave one out cross validation" (LOOCV) using spss?

Comment: I don't understand what the "i.e. not model accuracy" is doing in 2. It doesn't seem related to anything. Can you clarify or delete that?

Comment: thnax for your answer
my question is about the way that i can use Leave-one-out cross validation to validate a simple linear regression

Comment: Yoy seem to need an advanced analysis. You should definitely switch to some better language than SPSS, such as R.  Also, leave-one-out is probably not good to test prediction ability, it perturbs the model to little.